# Can't find created directory on zfs

Tags: zfs, zpool

I'm using openSUSE 13.1.

I created a new directory on a zpool

```
zfs create zpgd0/iSCSI -o compression=lz4 -o atime=off
```

but I'm not looking on that...
So I do it again but I'm getting...

```
zfs create zpgd0/iSCSI -o compression=lz4 -o atime=off
cannot create 'zpgd0/iSCSI': dataset already exists
```

adding some data

```
zpool history 
History for 'zpgd0':
2014-08-11.13:38:21 zpool create -f zpgd0 raidz2 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0490461 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0603473 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0606817 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0670246 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0673599 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0715212 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0722699 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0731193 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0732862 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0806663 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0807385 scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0816943
2014-08-11.14:13:09 zpool set autoexpand=on zpgd0
2014-08-11.14:14:32 zfs create zpgd0/espacio
2014-08-19.11:47:47 zfs create zpgd0/iSCSI -o compression=lz4 -o atime=off

 zpool status -v
  pool: zpgd0
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zpgd0                                           ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0490461  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0603473  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0606817  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0670246  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0673599  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0715212  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0722699  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0731193  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0732862  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0806663  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0807385  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_WDC_WD4001FAEX-0_WD-WMC1F0816943  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I have no errors but the folder does not appear, so what Can I do?

sorry add it

```
zfs list
NAME          USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zpgd0         933K  35,5T  54,7K  /zpgd0
zpgd0/iSCSI  54,7K  35,5T  54,7K  /zpgd0/iSCSI
```

Comment: What is the output of `zfs list`?

Comment: sorry added that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new filesystem is in `/zpgd0/iSCSI`. To access it, you can `cd /zpgd0/iSCSI`.

If it is not currently mounted, you can use `zfs mount zpgd0/iSCSI`.

---

Due to the naming of the filesystem, I'm betting that you probably want to create a ZFS zvol to present as block storage for iSCSI. If that's the case, what you're doing is taking you down the wrong path.

Comment: ok did not worked with cd... I'm very new to this wit zfs mount worked out. thanks!

Comment: You said that I was taking down the wronkg path... why do you say so?

Comment: @maniat1k because you have to supply the `-V <size>` parameter to your `zfs create` call to set up volumes. Also, you probably also want `-s` for sparse allocation. What you have done is creating another data set to host files, it would not work as a block device equivalent.

Comment: Ahh, now I see what you mean. We are not going to expose the raw space to iSCSI but several files which are the speciffic iSCSI fileio devices.